# How do I find $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

I stumbled across this problem to find the result of the following expression:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^n}$$

but I don't know how to approach it. It was suggested to me that I try this:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n\ln n}$$
However, I still don't know what to do. How can I find a closed form?

Comment: do you need the convergence? than compare to $n!$ or $n^2$ or something like that

Comment: there is no known closed form, but there is an integral with the same value.

Comment: I want to find a closed form for the sum.

Comment: There is no closed form and this has been asked before, by me, for example, and it was closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Could you close the question as a duplicate of that then? and what is the integral?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream and I have no rights to close anything :D

Comment: flag it I mean. I'll close it if I get the link.

Comment: See my comment above for the link to a previous version to the question.

Comment: @Jake223 : Please don't write n\ ln\ n.  Instead write n\ln n.  The backslash on \ln not only prevent it from being italicized as if the letters were variables, but also results in proper spacing.  TeX is not the work of primitive cave men; it is sophisticated.  (I edited the question accordingly.)

Comment: While we are here, what are the chances to find $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n! \tan \left(\frac{1}{n^n}\right)$?

Comment: in terms of integral i think i saw this sum and was equal to $$ \int_{0}^{1}dxx^{-x}= \sum_{1}^{\infty}n^{-n} $$

Comment: I would like to mention that I am (with @Marvis) (though much delayed) working on a paper that generalizes the sophomore's dream series and integrals as a kind of deformed exponential.